# Rails 4 update instance variables without page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way I can reload an instance variable in the view without reloading the page?

I have an AJAX post, and it creates a new record. I want that record to then be added to the existing instance variable.

So I have an action such as `action` and it handles the view I am in `action.html.erb`:

```
def action
  @variable = Variable.where().to_a
end
```

And then I have an AJAX request that executes an action such as `action2`:

```
def action2
  @new_record = Variable.create(params)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json {render :json => @new_record.to_json}
  end
end
```

Is there a way I can then refresh the `@variable` instance variable to include the newly created record?

Could I make another AJAX request to `action`? If so, how would I detect the AJAX request in `action`?

I have tried this^^ with `request.xhr?` but it is throwing a weird `StandardError` after I execute a JS `.click()`?

I'm not sure if I am going in the right direction, but if I am, here is all the code that I put together...

I am building an instant messaging service, and I admit that I am totally hacking together a prototype. I understand there are cleaner ways to do this that will handle high traffic loads, but I am working on a prototype right now.

The view code looks like this... there is: the HTML chatbox, I make an AJAX request to find new messages every 2 seconds, in the same function I make the AJAX request to what I called `action` above (actually names something different), after the "refresh" function I have a `.click()` function to update the users view (the one who just submitted).

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
        <p class="welcome">Welcome, <b></b></p>
        <p class="logout"><a id="exit" href="#">Exit Chat</a></p>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="chatbox">
      <% @messages.each do |message| %>
        <% if session[:email] == message.email %>
          <!-- post to the right side -->
          <div id="right-side">
            <p>Email: <%= message.email %></p>
            <p>Message: <%= message.message %></p>
          </div>
        <% else %>
          <!-- post to the left side -->
          <div id="left-side">
            <p>Email: <%= message.email %></p>
            <p>Message: <%= message.message %></p>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <form id="frm1" action="">
      Message: <input id="message_input" type="text" name="fname"><br>
      <!-- <input type="submit" value="Submit"> -->
      <button name="submitmsg" type="submit"  id="submitmsg">Try it</button>
    </form>
</div>

<p id="demo"></p>
<script>

  function retrieveMessages(){
    var message;
    $.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url:"<%= get_messages_path %>",
      dataType:"json",
      data: {chat_id: <%= @message_info[:chat_id] %>,
              last_message: <%= @messages.last.created_at.to_i %>},
      success:function(data){
        if (data != null){
          console.log(data);
          console.log(data.message);
          message = data.message;
          document.getElementById("chatbox").innerHTML +=  message + '<br>';
        }
      }
    });

    $.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url:"<%= new_message_path %>",
      dataType:"json",
      success:function(data){
        console.log("success!");
        }
      }
    });
    setTimeout(retrieveMessages, 2000);
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
    //get messages
    setTimeout(retrieveMessages, 2000);

    //send messages
    $("#submitmsg").on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var x = document.getElementById("frm1"); //This is the form, and not the value of the textbox
      var text = "";
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < x.length ;i++) {
        text += x.elements[i].value;
      }
      // document.getElementById("chatbox").innerHTML += text;
      text_with_br = text + "<br>"
      document.getElementById("chatbox").innerHTML += text_with_br;
      document.getElementById("frm1").reset();
      // console.log(document.getElementById("right"));
      //Actual message is in 'text'
      $.ajax({
        url: "/messages",
        method: "post",
        data: { message: text,
                chat_id: <%= @message_info[:chat_id] %>,
                message_counter: <%= @message_info[:message_counter] + 1 %> },
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(response){
          //do something,maybe notify user successfully posted their message
        },
        error: function(error){
          console.log(error);
        }
      });

    });
  });
</script>
```

Then for the `action` action I have (actually the `new` action, and what I called `@variable` is actually `@messages`:

```
def new
  # debugger
  # Message.create(:chat_id => 5)
  if session[:email].nil?
    #user not logged in
    redirect_to new_session_path(:message => "need to login")
  else
      @user = User.where(:email => session[:email]).first
      @message_info = Hash(email: @user.email, message_counter: 0, chat_id: Message.last.chat_id + 1)
      @messages = Message.where(:chat_id => @message_info[:chat_id]).to_a

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json
      end

  end
end
```

Then the action that executes the AJAX request to GET the most recent message (so that viewers from other browsers can view) is as follow...

```
def get
  @new_message = Message.where(["created_at > ?", Time.at(params[:last_message].to_i)]).first

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    # format.json {render json: @new_message}
    format.json {render :json => @new_message.to_json}
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**

@eggroll suggested code below, but I'm running into bootstrap issues

[image]

Comment: I will suggest you to just append the div to the $("#chatbox") on the ajax success callback. the div contain the response @variable

Comment: @power won't it still just insert a duplicate message to the HTML DOM? Also the main problem I have is that when I pass the param `last_message: <%= @messages.last.created_at.to_i %>` in the AJAX GET function it will only send the last message since the page was loaded -- I need a way to append the most recent message to the `@message` variable

Comment: in that case you can just find the last message by new_message = Message.order("created_at").last, and then compare its created_at with the Time.at(params[:last_message].to_i) if the new_message.created_at is greater that means you got the new_message but if its equal which means you have not got any new message so just send nil to response. make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from your code, below is my attempt at a solution. I've renamed elements in the hope that it will make this code more self-documenting and therefore easier for you to discern what I've done. It's not perfect, but it is working for me in Chrome, so hopefully it helps. I have assumed the starting `chat_id` is 1. If it is not, you can adjust it in the `get_last_chat_id` method in the controller.

*(Note: There are a few lines of code that will be superfluous for you, but were necessary for me to be able to run this code inside of one of my existing apps. You should also know that I'm using Postgres, jQuery, Devise, HAML and Bootstrap 4 alpha.)*

**app/controllers/messages_controller.rb**

```rb
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_current_user_email, only: [:index, :display_all_messages]
  before_action :set_current_messages,   only: [:display_all_messages]

  def index
  end


  def get_last_chat_id
    last_chat_id = Message.pluck(:chat_id).max
    if last_chat_id
      puts '*** LAST CHAT ID: ' + last_chat_id.to_s
    else
      last_chat_id = 0
      puts '*** LAST CHAT ID: ' + last_chat_id.to_s
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: last_chat_id }
    end
  end


  def save_new_message
    new_message = Message.new do |msg|
      msg.email        = params[:email]
      msg.message_text = params[:message_text]
      msg.chat_id      = params[:chat_id]
    end

    puts '*** NEW MESSAGE EMAIL:   ' + new_message.email
    puts '*** NEW MESSAGE TEXT:    ' + new_message.message_text
    puts '*** NEW MESSAGE CHAT ID: ' + new_message.chat_id.to_s

    # Source: https://makandracards.com/housetrip-deck/16879-jquery-ajax-success-done-will-not-run-callbacks-if-request-is-json-but-the-response-is-empty-typical-200
    respond_to do |format|
      if new_message.save
        puts '*** NEW MESSAGE WAS SAVED!!!'
        format.json { render json: { ok: true }, status: :ok }
      else
        puts '*** NEW MESSAGE WAS NOT SAVED!!!'
        format.json { render json: { ok: false }, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def display_all_messages
    respond_to do |format|
      if @current_messages
        format.js  {  }
      else
        puts '*** THERE ARE NO MESSAGES TO DISPLAY!!!'
      end
    end
  end


  private

    def set_current_messages
      @current_messages = Message.by_created_desc
    end


    def set_current_user_email
      @current_user_email = current_user.email
    end


    def message_params
      params.require(:message).
        permit(:email, :message_text)
    end


end
```

**app/models/message.rb**

```rb
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :by_created_desc, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }

end
```

**db/migrate/20160717000100_create_messages.rb**

```rb
class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change

    create_table :messages do |t|

      t.string  :email,        null: false
      t.text    :message_text
      t.integer :chat_id,      null: false

      t.timestamps null: false

    end

    add_index :messages, :chat_id, unique: true

  end
end
```

**app/assets/javascripts/messages.js** (Updated 2016-07-17)

```js
var messagesRefresher;

$(document).ready(function(){

  // AJAX error handling, outputting error messaging to the console
  $(document).ajaxError(function (event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError) {
    console.log('EVENT: '        + JSON.stringify(event, null, '\t'));
    console.log('JQXHR: '        + JSON.stringify(jqxhr));
    console.log('SETTINGS: '     + JSON.stringify(settings, null, '\t'));
    console.log('THROWN ERROR: ' + thrownError);
  });

  messagesRefresher = setInterval(refreshMessages, 2000);

  $('#new-message-create-btn').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#new-message-create-btn').addClass('no-display');
    $('#new-message-form-wrapper').removeClass('no-display');
  });

  $('#new-message-cancel-btn').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#new-message-form-wrapper').addClass('no-display');
    $('#new-message-create-btn').removeClass('no-display');
  });

  $('#new-message-submit-btn').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var newMessageEmail  = $('#new-message-email').val();
    var newMessageText   = $('#new-message-text').val();

    console.log('*** NEW MESSAGE EMAIL: ' + newMessageEmail);
    console.log('*** NEW MESSAGE TEXT:');
    console.log(newMessageText);

    getLastChatId('/messages/get_last_chat_id').done(function(lastChatId) {
      var newMessageChatId = lastChatId + 1;
      console.log('*** NEW MESSAGE CHAT ID: ' + newMessageChatId)

      saveNewMessage('/messages/save_new_message?email=' + newMessageEmail + '&message_text=' + newMessageText + '&chat_id=' + newMessageChatId).done(function(data) {

        console.log('*** MESSAGE # ' + newMessageChatId + ' SAVED!!!')

        $('#new-message-form-wrapper').addClass('no-display');
        document.getElementById('new-message-form').reset();
        $('#new-message-create-btn').removeClass('no-display');

        refreshMessages;
      });

    });

  });

});


function refreshMessages() {
  displayAllMessages('/messages/display_all_messages').done(function(data) {
    console.log('*** MESSAGES REFRESHED!!!');
  });
};


function getLastChatId(url) {
  return $.ajax({
    url:       url,
    type:     'get',
    dataType: 'json'
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert('AJAX Get Last Chat Id Error');
  });
};


function saveNewMessage(url) {
  return $.ajax({
    url:       url,
    type:     'get',
    dataType: 'json'
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert('AJAX Save New Message Error');
  });
};


function displayAllMessages(url) {
  return $.ajax({
    url:       url,
    type:     'get',
    dataType: 'script'
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert('AJAX Display All Messages Error');
  });
};


$(window).unload(
  function(event) {
    clearInterval(messagesRefresher);
  }
);
```

**app/views/layouts/application.html.haml (snippet)** (Added: 2016-07-18)

```
.
.
.

%head

  %meta{ charset: 'UTF-8' }
  %meta{ name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no' }

  -# Derived from: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/browsers-devices/
  %meta{ 'http-equiv' => 'X-UA-Compatible', content: 'IE=edge' }

  = csrf_meta_tags

  -# For page-specific meta tags
  = content_for?(:meta_tag) ? yield(:meta_tag) : ""

  %title Chatbox

  = stylesheet_link_tag 'application'
  = yield :page_stylesheet_link_tags

  = javascript_include_tag 'application'
  = yield :page_specific_javascript

.
.
.
```

**app/views/messages/index.html.haml**

```
- content_for :page_specific_javascript do
  = javascript_include_tag 'messages.js'

#chatbox
  %h1 Chatbox

  = link_to 'New Message', 'javascript:;', id: 'new-message-create-btn', class: 'btn btn-sm btn-primary'

  #new-message-form-wrapper.no-display
    = form_tag messages_path, id: 'new-message-form' do
      = hidden_field_tag 'new-message-email', @current_user_email
      #new-message-form-label-wrapper
        = label_tag 'new-message-text', 'Enter Your Message:'
      #new-message-form-text-wrapper
        = text_area_tag 'new-message-text', nil, rows: 6, cols: 70
      #new-message-form-buttons-wrapper
        = submit_tag 'Post Message', id: 'new-message-submit-btn', class: 'btn btn-sm btn-success'
        = link_to 'Cancel', 'javascript:;', id: 'new-message-cancel-btn', class: 'btn btn-sm btn-secondary'


  #display-messages-wrapper

    #messages-column-left.pull-md-left
      %h3 Messages From Others
      #messages-other-users

    #messages-column-right.pull-md-right
      %h3 My Messages
      #messages-current-user
```

**app/views/messages/display_all_messages.js.haml**

```js
$('#messages-other-users').html('');
$('#messages-current-user').html('');
- @current_messages.each do |msg|
  - if msg.email == @current_user_email
    $('#messages-current-user').append("#{ escape_javascript render(partial: 'message', locals: { email: msg.email, message_created_at: msg.created_at, message_text: msg.message_text }) }");
  - else
    $('#messages-other-users').append("#{ escape_javascript render(partial: 'message', locals: { email: msg.email, message_created_at: msg.created_at, message_text: msg.message_text }) }");
```

**app/views/messages/_message.html.haml**

```
.message-wrapper

  .message-attribution-wrapper
    %span.message-attribution-label Posted by:
    %span.message-attribution-text=email + ' on ' + message_created_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + ' at ' + message_created_at.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p')

  .message-text-wrapper
    .message-label Message:
    .message-text= message_text
```

**app/assets/stylesheets/messages.scss** (Updated 2016-07-17)

```css
.no-display {
  display: none !important;
}

#chatbox {
  width: 90%;
  margin: .5em auto;
}

#new-message-form-wrapper {
  width: 48%;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#new-message-form-label-wrapper > label {
  font-weight: 700;
}

#new-message-form-buttons-wrapper {
  margin-top: .5em;
}

#new-message-submit-btn {
  margin-right: .3em;
}

#new-message-submit-btn,
#new-message-cancel-btn {
  width: 8em;
}

#new-messages-form-wrapper,
#display-messages-wrapper {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
}

#messages-column-left,
#messages-column-right {
  width: 48%;
}

.message-wrapper {
  width: 96%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  padding: .5em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.message-attribution-label,
.message-label {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

**config/routes.rb**

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :messages, only: [:index]
  get  'messages/get_last_chat_id',     to: 'messages#get_last_chat_id'
  get  'messages/save_new_message',     to: 'messages#save_new_message'
  get  'messages/display_all_messages', to: 'messages#display_all_messages'

end
```

**assests/javascripts/application.js** (Added: 2016-07-18)

```js
//= require jquery 
//= require jquery_ujs 
//= require jquery-ui 
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

**config/initialization/assets/rb** (Added: 2016-07-18)

```rb
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( messages.js )
```

**assets/stylesheets/application.scss** (Added: 2016-07-18)

```css
@import 'bootstrap_4a/bs_4a_variable_overrides'; 
@import 'bootstrap'; 
@import 'bootstrap_4a/bs_4a_customization';
```

**app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_4a/bs_4a_variable_overrides** (Added: 2016-07-18)

```css
// http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/flexbox/
// Enabling flexbox means reduced browser and device support:
//   Internet Explorer 9 and below do not support flexbox.
//   Internet Explorer 10 has a few known quirks, requires using a prefix,
//   and only supports the syntax from the old 2012 version of the spec.

$enable-flex: true;
```

**app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_4a/bs_4a_customization** (Added: 2016-07-18)

```css
// http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/browsers-devices/
// As of Safari v8.0, fixed-width .containers can cause Safari
// to use an unusually small font size when printing.
// One potential workaround for this is adding the following CSS:

  @media print {
    .container {
      width: auto;
    }
  }

  body {
    position: relative;
  }
```

**Gemfile** (Added: 2016-07-18)

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0' 
gem 'jquery-rails' 
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 5.0.5' 
gem 'autoprefixer-rails', '~> 6.3.6' 
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.alpha3'
```

**UPDATE: .js.erb** version of **apps/views/messages/display_all_messages.js.haml**

```rb
$('#messages-other-users').html('');
$('#messages-current-user').html('');
<% @current_messages.each do |msg| %>
  <% if msg.email == @current_user_email %>
    $('#messages-current-user').append("<%= escape_javascript render(partial: 'message', locals: { email: msg.email, message_created_at: msg.created_at, message_text: msg.message_text }) %>");
  <% else %>
     $('#messages-other-users').append("<%= escape_javascript render(partial: 'message', locals: { email: msg.email, message_created_at: msg.created_at, message_text: msg.message_text }) %>");
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Updated `messages.scss` to include `.no-display`.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't completely sure it did what you were looking to do, but it sounds like it does. Cheers!

Comment: I've actually never even used HAML. Do you know a good starter tutorial?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I've just picked it up over time. It's pretty easy to pick up the basics, but you'll end up visiting SO to get past some of the nuances or unusal cases. I originally didn't like it because it didn't have the symmetry of erb, but once I committed to using it, I prefer how much cleaner it is.  You can always convert what I've done in HAML with [link](https://haml2erb.org/) although it may require a few tweaks.  The one that might be tricky is the `display_all_messages.js.haml` file. It won't convert that correctly, so I will add the ERB version I did first to get it working.

Comment: Fixed typo in **app/assets/javascripts/messages.js** (`#new-messages-form-wrapper` => `#new-message-form-wrapper`).

Comment: "New Message" link_to does nothing. I converted to `.erb`

Comment: Seems to be a bootstrap problem -- check post for console errors

Comment: Did you fix the same typo error I fixed above? It appears in a few places in that js file.

Comment: I did, and I resolved the bootstrap issue. Now I just have the `$` error and `JQuery` error

Comment: I added a `console.log()` inside the `#new-message-create-btn` and it isn't exeecuting, some sort of JQuery error. `aaplication.js` has the `//= require jquery` -- updated picture in post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117636/discussion-between-eggroll-and-kendall-weihe).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the success callback, and append the div to the $("#chatbox"), following is the sample code for that.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: loadUrl,
    data: dataString,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(response) {
        $("#chatbox").append("
        <div id="left-side">
        <p>Email:"+  response[:email]+"</p>
        <p>Message:"+ response[:message]+"</p>
      </div>"
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you respond to my comment above?